# How do i read API directly from a site?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, console

Good Afternoon everyone,

Problem: I have recently made a javascript function to be run on google chrome console. it was fine but one day when i loaded var dictionary = {5000 lines of data}, it lags.

the data is from an API from another site. My question is how do i load it into my script directly from the site which provides the data.

Secondly, in the API there are symbols such as * and ^ that i want to remove, can we remove it after loading from the site.

What i am currently doing: I go to the api site, copy all the data and paste it into a text file, i replace the * and ^ with blanks, then i copy all this 5000lines of data into my javascript like

var dictionary = {a:1, b:2,c:3,...}

but this lags the system :(

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is one of those few points where js doesn't shine. It does and will probably always lag while dealing with such an amount of data. That's one reason why APIs use 'pagination', so that the response data is divided into pages which load quicker and are read by js quicker. Look for pagination parameters in the API maybe.

As far as the replacement of those symbols is concerned, well, that's kinda unfortunate. At best, use the data as is, but whenever you return that data, replace the symbol at that point and return. Meaning, deal with the data as it is, but while outputting it for user or whatever, do a quick string replacement there and then carry on.